# How can I hide a few files from my phpstorm project

Tags: phpstorm

In my PhpStorm project, I have a few files that sit in the root folder and are not modified often.[image]

For example here I rarely touch files like `favicon, gruntfile, humans, package, robots, gitignore`. So out of all 9 files I only need 3. I can not remove them (they still needed for the project) and they distract my attention.

So I am looking for a way to hide/exclude them. I was able to find [similar approach with folders](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22560866/1090562), but it works only with folders. On official phpstorm page there is a page which [sounds similar](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/excluding-files-from-project.html) but does something completely different (files still stay in the few, you just can not autocomplete anything from them). Also this [answer from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11136261/1090562) is also dealing with code inspection, not hiding files.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

1. `Settings | Scopes`
2. Create new scope that would include only files/folders you want (or opposite: exclude all unwanted files/folders)
3. Use that scope in Project View panel instead of default "Project"

Comment: This is awesome, thanks! Really handy if you are just working on a feature and want to only see the relevant files in big lists.

Comment: Thanks! exactly what I searched for

Answer (score 26):

Or even easier: click on the gear icon in the project pane and untick "Show excluded files".

Comment: Ugh, how frustrating it is when not even *this* one works! Thanks though, really useful to know

Comment: This works, but toggling that setting only updates files once. I have to do this every time I have any changes to my file tree to see them, and it doesn't matter if I set it on or off - only that I toggled it. That's in `vendor` directory for composer, Phpstorm 2019.1.3

Comment: Newer PhpStorm versions have this option under the `Project Panel > Gear Icon Button > Tree Appearance > Show Excluded Files`

Answer (score 1):

For later versions of PhpStorm (I'm using PhpStorm 2022.1):

1. Exclude unwanted files or folders
2. Open preferences
3. Search for `show excluded`
4. Under the Keymap menu, define a shortcut for toggling `Show Excluded Files` and press `OK`
5. Use the shortcut in the IDE to show/hide excluded files