# WebStorm/PhpStorm: files missing from project view

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm

I'm working in `PhpStorm 2017.3` but this probably applies to many IDEA IDEs. A while back (on an earlier version) I made a change to project settings that hid `.spec.ts` files from the project view. I'd like to undo it but I can't figure out what it was.

Here are files in a folder as they appear in the IDE:

[image]

Here is the same folder in my OS file explorer. Notice all the `spec.ts` files:

[image]

I thought maybe the setting had to do with Scopes after reading [LazyOne's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23930035/3977061). However I have no scope defined in this project:

[image]

I also thought that perhaps I had added these files to the list of excluded files in `Settings > Directories` but turns out this list has a couple of irrelevant directories but no specific file:

[image]

What did I do to hide these files and how can I undo it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setting in question had to do with `Settings > Editor > File Types` pane.  See the *Ignore files and folders* section of [this doc page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/file-types.html)

I had added `*.spec.ts` to my list, causing the IDE to pretend those files don't exist at all.

[image]